# Pandas replace turns out NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I've recently started experimenting with pandas for Python. I've loaded a dataframe from excell which results in the following:

```
Datum   Fotonummer  Werkput Vlak    Spoornummer Oriëntatie  Onderwerp   Fotograaf                               
2011-05-16  1          1    1.0        1           N     Vlakfoto Spoor 1   DIM
2011-05-16  2          1    1.0        1           N     Vlakfoto Spoor 1   DIM
2011-05-16  3          1    1.0        1           N     Vlakfoto Spoor 1   DIM
```

At some points the column 'Spoornummer' contains multiple values seperated by a '-'.

```
2011-05-16  24         1    1.0    12 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 16   N   Vlakfoto Spoor 12 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 16   DIM
2011-05-16  25         1    1.0    17 - 18                  N   Vlakfoto Spoor 17 - 18                  DIM
2011-05-16  26         1    1.0    17 - 18                  N   Vlakfoto Spoor 17 - 18                  DIM
```

I wanted to replace the '-' by a '|' for easy usage in a Neo4J db, and tried to do so using:

```
df['Spoornummer'] = df['Spoornummer'].str.replace('-', '|')
```

and other variations, but to no avail. On executing the command the entire 'Spoornummer' column gets a NaN value.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - this works for me.

Comment: That code should work fine. Did you happen to blank out your column in your other attempts so you're running that code on an already blank column?

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: Did OP accidentaly end up providing right answer while posting a question ? Which pandas version are you using ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sub()` from re and apply it to every row in colum Spoornummer:

```
import re
df['Spoornummer'] = df['Spoornummer'].apply(lambda x: re.sub("-", "|", x))
```